# How to mongoengine ListField(ImageField())

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a model as bellow

```py
class Post(Document):
    id = IntField(primary_key=True)
    text = StringField()
    images = ListField(ImageField())
```

and I need to save images for each post in a list named `images` as in the code above. But I don't know how to use `ImageField` inside a `ListField`. Googling didn't take me anywhere.
How could saving be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling with the term `ImageGridFsProxy`, I found that it was an issue for others and discussed [here](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/643). But the final answer is definitely [here](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/issues/86).

Thanks.